# Howto use encodeFunctionCall with nested, array or non-string parameters?

Tags: web3js, struct, abi, encodefunctioncall

Web3.js has a method named [encodefunctioncall](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctioncall) with the following signature:

`encodeFunctionCall(abiItem: AbiItem, params: string[]): string;`

The first parameter is ABI interface of that function and the seconds one is a string array of function parameters. My problem is with the second parameter, it only accepts string array, while my method gets a struct and some address and int arrays as input. If I use `encodeParameters` to encode my input parameters, it returns a single string that can't be passed to `encodefunctioncall` since it only accepts string array as its second input:

`encodeParameters(types: any[], paramaters: any[]): string;`

How can I create my function call with non-string (e.g. nested structs or arrays) using web3.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to calculate function signature and parameters separately using web3 ABI encoder functions and then simply concatenate them:

```
const callData = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature(abiItem) + web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(types, params).substr(2)/* remove preceding 0x */;
```

More info is available at [this link](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html).